# How to get the virtual storage size of a process continuously?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

We all know that `top` command monitors the running processes continuously. I have an application that is running continuously in an embedded Linux and I need to monitor its VSZ (Virtual storage size) value from the `top` command, I mean while the application is running, every period of time get the VSZ value and log it (Well basically get the value at least first). How to get the VSZ value in such context ? Is it possible in C/C++, bash, any other method ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a Linux kernel, you can refer to `/proc/[PID]/stat` (defined in `/usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c`).
It contains numerous fields, the 23rd is the virtual memory size in bytes (see `man proc`).

Alternatively, you also have `/proc/[PID]/statm` which contains only values about memory (in pages), or, more human readable, `/proc/[PID]/status`.

All these informations are detailed in `man proc`.

Use `cat` command to view these files.

Comment: Well that's odd, the embedded device I have shows all those files as empty while they are not on my opensuse machine. :\

Comment: @3bdalla I have no embedded device to test... Is this link relevant for you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/no-proc-in-a-busybox-based-embedded-linux-distribution ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The /proc folder exists and it has subdirectories for each process. The stat* files are empty that's the problem. Unfortunately I didn't build the kernel for the device, it came already built and running. :\

Comment: `cat /proc/[PID]/stat` works like a charm! I was using `vi` and still no idea why it did not work.

Comment: @3bdalla cool :)

Comment: I'm doing some tests and will accept your answer upon success, it would be better if you update your question to use the `cat` command.

Answer (score 1):

With `ps -eo vsz,comm` you can list both the VSZ and command values. Then you can combine that in a subroutine (shell script) as:

```
while true
do
    ps -eo vsz,comm | grep process-i-want >> /path/to/output
    sleep 1
done
```

You can also substitute `>> /path/to/output` with `| tee /path/to/output` if you want to see and log the output.

Comment: This is good. The embedded device can show the VSZ value but no `-eo` options. I'm thinking of reading the command using `popen` and making it continuously run using a cron-job. Will update when I try it, thanks!